# finding the minimum of 2 numbers in an array in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[42] = {-16748, 1861305,
-1677019, 2959868,
8279642, -5614317,
-6959809, -8869681,
5841371, 684147,
9078506, -9854715,
5442553, -8007477,
5455657, 400271,
-8326571, -589876,
-2139466, 7869921,
9462518, 8289564,
-1158751, -1908990,
3315049, 5073796,
-2511851, 6631645,
960911, 5459324,
9951099, 7368220,
1403411, -6792887,
2886747, 4303636,
-4393903, -1918146,
-2402605, -1947543,
-6002778, -7925503,
};
    int b[21];
    for (int i=0; i<=42; i+=2)
    {
        int n=0;
        if (i == 0) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1])
                b[i] = a[i+1];
            else if (a[i] < a[i+1])
                b[i] = a[i];
        } 
        else if (i > 0) {
            if (a[i] > a[i+1])
                b[i-n] = a[i+1];
            else if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
                b[i-n] = a[i];
            }    
        }
        n++;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=21; i++)
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

I was solving a problem on finding the minimum between two and I'm not getting the right output

the output looks like this:

```
-16748 32765 -1677019 0 -5614317 32765 -8869681 32560 684147 32560 -9854715 0 -8007477 32560 400271 32560 -8326571 0 -2139466 32765 8289564 0
```

I've been trying this for 30 minutes but haven't been successful.

Note: I'm a beginner to c++

Comment: I honestly don't understand what your program is trying to accomplish.  Minimum of what two numbers?  You have a single array of 42 values.  If you clarify what this program is supposed to do, you more than likely would get much more optimal answers to your question that actually uses idiomatic C++, instead of hard-coded `for` loops.

Comment: Trying to decipher the problem, maybe it would have been much easier if you had `std::pair<int, int> a[] = {{-16748, 1861305}, {8279642, -5614317},...};`.  Then it is a one line `for` loop, without all of the messing around with all sorts of array subscript issues.

Comment: Is [this the correct output?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/395e7954ae331871)  If so, you see the power of C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple statements which you need to correct.

Firstly

```cpp
    for (int i=0; i<=42; i+=2)
```

Your array size is 42, so the indices to loop are from 0 to 41(inclusive). However, your loop also reaches 42, which will cause undefined behaviour(which is generally bad), so the correct way would be

```cpp
    for (int i=0; i < 42; i+=2)
```

Similarly for when you print `b`,

```cpp
    for (int i=0; i<=21; i++) //incorrect
    for (int i=0; i < 21; i++) //correct
```

Lastly, the code to find minimum, it can be done far more easily like this,

```cpp
for (int i=0; i < 42; i+=2)
{
    b[i/2] = min(a[i], a[i + 1]); 
}

// OR you can do this

for (int i=0; i < 21; i++)
{
    b[i] = min(a[2 * i], a[2 * i + 1]); 
}
```

Comment: // b[i/2] = min(a[i], a[i + 1]); This worked wonderfully. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped. You can accept my answer if it satisfactorily answers your question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: also I just realized that I could've just replaced b[i-1] to b[1/2]. Well I still have to learn. None the less, thanks for the help.

Comment: Accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behavior, there is no guarantee of a segfault.

Comment: Thanks @JamesAdkison for pointing out the improvement. Fixed my answer.